# Dockerfile on Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: python, linux, docker, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to create a docker image on Raspberry Pi 3B+, which i couldn't managed for days. Before creating Docker image, i implemented the code with ***virtualenv*** beforehand, which is working fine and requirements.txt is simplified as possible.

**Dockerfile ->**

```
FROM alpine:3.14

WORKDIR /code

RUN apk update
RUN apk add python3
RUN apk add py3-pip

RUN pip install wheel
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow

# copy the requirements inside docker image
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

# install dependencies inside docker image
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

# copy the necessary files in the working directory inside docker image
COPY ./ /code

# RUN the code
CMD ["python3", "camera.py"]
```

**requirements.txt ->**

```
numpy==1.22.3
picamera==1.13
Pillow==9.1.0
requests==2.27.1
```

When i try to build the image by running

```
sudo docker build -t camera .
```

I get the following long error

> ```
>  Building wheels for collected packages: Pillow   Building wheel for
>  Pillow (setup.py): started   Building wheel for Pillow (setup.py):
>  finished with status 'error'   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [177 lines of output]
>   
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
>     File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
>     File "/tmp/pip-install- 
>     7613obru/pillow_a212af14addc481892cfcd3648121cf3/setup.py",
>   line 1009, in <module>
>       raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
>   __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
>   
>   The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
>   a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
>   
>   Please see the install instructions at:
>      https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
>   
>   
>   [end of output]
>  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow  
> Running setup.py clean for Pillow Failed to build Pillow Installing
> collected packages: Pillow   Running setup.py install for Pillow:
> started   Running setup.py install for Pillow: finished with status
> 'error'   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
> × Running setup.py install for Pillow did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [179 lines of output]
>   running install
>   running build
>   running build_py
>   creating build
>   creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9
>   creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/PIL
>   copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/PIL
>   copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/PIL
>   
>   
>   The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
>   a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
>   
>   Please see the install instructions at:
>      https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
>   
>    line 804, in build_extensions
>       raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
>   __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib
>   
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>   
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
>     File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
>     File "/tmp/pip-install- 
>     7613obru/pillow_a212af14addc481892cfcd3648121cf3/setup.py",
>    line 1009, in <module>
>       raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
>   __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
>   
>   The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
>   a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
>   
>   Please see the install instructions at:
>      https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
>   
>   
>   [end of output]
>   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: legacy-install-failure
>
>      × Encountered error while trying to install package. ╰─> Pillow
>
>      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
>      hint: See above for output from the failure.
> ```

I've deleted some repetitive lines of error since it was extremely long

Comment: There are development libraries missing. In your case `zlib`. Try `RUN apk add zlib-dev`. You may need more for a successful compile.

Comment: you are right, i've added zlib-dev with some more libraries, i will add the results

Answer (score 0):

It seems i have development libraries missing, i added the following lines and the error was solved

```
RUN apk add build-base python3-dev py-pip jpeg-dev zlib-dev py3-wheel py3-setuptools
ENV LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib
```